# How do I get rid of schema validation errors when mapping one-to-many to a "joined" child class in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an abstract `ContentItem` class which is a Doctrine entity with inheritance type `JOINED`. It's in a many-to-one relationship with `BusinessAccount` entity. `BusinessAccount` has one-to-many relationships to non-abstract subclasses of `ContentItem`, in particular `TextItem`, which are inverses of the aforementioned many-to-one relationship.

Here's the code: (unrelated parts removed)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
abstract class ContentItem
{
    /**
     * @var BusinessAccount
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=BusinessAccount::class)
     */
    protected $businessAccount;
}

/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BusinessAccount
{
    /**
     * @var Collection<TextItem>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TextItem::class, mappedBy="businessAccount")
     */
    private $textItems;
}

/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TextItem extends ContentItem
{
    // nothing interesting here
}
```

The idea is to guarantee that every `ContentItem` child class belongs to a `BusinessAccount`, at the same time separating different children into separate replationships on `BusinessAccount`'s side.

This code works perfectly fine, however it doesn't pass schema validation with Doctrine's `doctrine:schema:validate` command:

> Mapping
>
> [FAIL] The entity-class App\Application\BusinessAccount mapping is invalid:
>
> - The field App\Application\BusinessAccount#textItems is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity App\Entity\TextItem#businessAccount does not contain the required 'inversedBy="textItems"' attribute.

It seems to me that Doctrine correctly identifies `many-to-one` and `one-to-many` as two sides of one association, but it wants me to explicitly specify the name of inverse property on `ContentItem::$businessAccount`. I can't do this because there are multiple inverse properties, one per subclass of `ContentItem`.

I can remove these errors by moving the `$businessAccount` property to subclasses of `ContentItem`. I don't find this solution satisfying because it introduces code duplication, makes it hard to guarantee ownership of each `ContentItem` subtype and moves foreign keys to other tables.

I've tried to override the `$businessAccount` property in child classes with `inversedBy` specified, but it doesn't make the error go away.

Is there a clean solution that would let me resolve these errors?

Comment: @yivi Not overriding, moving. Overriding seems to [effectively create two properties with the same name](https://3v4l.org/s5Guj), one for superclass and one for child, even if Doctrine would somehow work I don't want such mess in the codebase. It must be a single property accessible both for parent and child.

Comment: You are creating two properties of the same name because you set it as `private`. Since you want to actually inherit the property, using `private` visibility makes no sense. If you use `protected` you'll be able to override the property on each of the children, and setup the appropriate annotations there. (https://3v4l.org/qRcvX)

Comment: @yivi I've tried to override the property, but Doctrine still finds the same error.

Comment: Are you writing the annotation both on the abstract parent and the children? Do it just in the children, since the parent annotation will always be broken.

Comment: @yivi While a bit better, that will move foreign key from `ContentItem`'s table to all child tables. I'd like to keep them in parent's tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this with [Association Overrides](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override).

Basically you'd have a correct and complete mapping in the parent entity (e.g. including the `inversed_by` property):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
abstract class ContentItem
{
    /**
     * @var BusinessAccount
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=BusinessAccount::class, inversedBy="textItems")
     */
    protected $businessAccount;
}
```

And then define the specific override in the children, when you need it:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="businessAccount",
 *          inversedBy="otherProperty"
 *      )
 * })
 */
class TextItem extends ContentItem
{
    // nothing interesting here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about association overrides. I have multiple subclasses of `ContentItem` with corresponding one-to-many for each in `BusinessAccount`. Specifying `inversedBy="textItems"` for all `ContentItem`s would be misleading.

Comment: I think you need to specify an inversedBy on the parent/abstract, otherwise the validation will fail.

Comment: Have a well-deserved upvote for now and thank you for your time. I'll give myself some time to explore other possibilities, but if I won't find a better solution, I'll make sure to accept your answer.